# Scroll on drag, move an div on long click and show a div on short click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, touch

In the following example:

codepen.io/irudha/pen/yLgqPeG

I am trying to achieve these:

The home button has a long and a short click event.

1. On click and release. The dropdown should show and also show the div called drag. When the drag div is visible and dragged up or down the page should scroll.
2. When clicked on home button and held for more than 2 seconds the function to move the menu around should fire up and should be able to place the menu wherever on wants. When released the menu should stay where it was release so that on the next quick click the menu and the drag option functions.

My issue:

All of what i described above works well on desktop browser and not on ipad or mobile.

I would be eternally grateful if someone can help me out and probably suggest a better way to do.

Comment: https://codepen.io/irudha/pen/yLgqPeG

Comment: You would have to include the same kind of mechanism for `touch` events...

Comment: Yes i realised that. I am not able to get that to work hence the post here hoping someone could help me with what to edit or add to what i have done.